# Windows XP over two monitors, but one of them switches off at boot... how to fix? How to switch back to one monitor?

Tags: windows-xp, multiple-monitors

When booting into XP (x64, Athlon II X2 245, 4GB RAM), my main monitor (got two 19" TFTs hooked up, two gfx cards, a 4650 (1GB, the primary monitor's on this) and a 4350 (512MB)) switches off. Logging in blind (cursor down key, typing password) gets me one screen, the secondary.

Booted correctly until about two days ago.  No clue what's the cause, last change was (if I don't overlook something) installing the ATI 9-12 hotfix. And booting into Windows 7, after returning from 7, it was like this.

For some weird reason, I cannot start Catalyst Control Center (I right-click desktop, choose the CCC entry, the pointer changes to hourglass for a half-second... and nothing.  Likewise with "Properties"... I think, as all windows open on the primary (off) screen, and no entry appears in the task bar for Properties)

Completely stumped.  Windows 7, same setup, works w/o a hitch.

The primary monitor appears to run in some unknown, but pretty low, resolution, as the mouse pointer only moves onto it at about half-height. But, w/o CCC or display properties, I cannot check. And, obviously, not change anything.

Hope this was not too long-winded.  And I'm sure I still forgot essential stuff. :P

Answer (score 0):

uninstall catalyst driver, then reinstall with the latest.  download from amd site.